# get value of inputText on the fly without backing bean?

Tags: java, html, jsf

can I get the value of a inputTextare on the fly without backing bean?

```
<p:dialog>
<p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" value="#{_var.note}" />
<h:outputText id="remaining" value="#{util.getCharactersRemaining("varibale of textarea", 160)} characters left" />



public class UtilFacade {
    public int getCharactersRemaining(String value, int maxLength) {
        log.info("length: " + value.length());
        return (maxLength - value.length());
    }
}
```

In order to display the remaining chars in the dialog, I have to feed the method with current value in Textarea without saving the value to a backing bean!
How can i get this value?

Comment: Did you try `#{util.getCharactersRemaining(_var.note, 160)}`?

Comment: Not really sure what you want here.  If you want a realtime notification then you will need to put a custom jQuery keypress handler function on the inputTextArea to perform an immediate validation without a server side postback.  Otherwise if you want the outputText to display a validation message then you should use an `<f:validateLength>` facet on the inputTextArea to ensure that your input does not exceed the max length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a JavaScript method (no need to go to server). Here is a sample:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRemainingChars(textArea, maxLength) {
        var actualText = textArea.value;
        if (actualText.length > maxLength) {
            textArea.value = actualText.substring(0, maxLength);
        }
        var remainingChars = (maxLength > actualText.length) ? maxLength - actualText.length : 0;
        document.getElementById("frmMyPage:txtRemainingChars").value = remainingChars;
    }
</script>
<h:form id="frmMyPage">
<h:inputTextArea id="txtTextArea" cols="50" rows="10" onkeyup="getRemainingChars(this, 500);" />
<br />
<h:outputText id="txtRemainingChars" />
</h:form>
```

You can get more details about `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup` javascript functions [here](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx) (in this case I preffer to validate the text on the keyup event). Also you can modify the JavaScript function and send the id of your component instead of sending the whole component (this will make the JS available for inputText component and similars).

Comment: +1 but I think that this line will not work for the OP `document.getcomponentById("frmMyPage:txtRemainingChars")` Despite the fact that this function does not exist on `document`, the use of the JSF value `_var` suggests that this is within a `c:forEach` or a `ui:repeat` component, in which case the id `frmMyPage:txtRemainingChars` will likely not be found.

Comment: @maple: having a dialog inside a repeater component is also highly questionable design.